# Bootstrap 3 - manually asigning active class to to header nav items

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nav walker for bootstrap in wordpress.

I have added a Custom Nav item from admin panel under menus. That custom item has 3 sub pages, when I go to one of the pages under that custom item, the page link highlights and the class "active" applies but I want the custom nav item or parent nav item to be active also.

How can I do this?

I tried below code but this doesn't work

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentLocation = location.pathname;
   if (currentLocation == "media-gallery/pictures"){
      $("#menu-item-140").addClass("active");
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentLocation = location.pathname;
   alert(currentLocation);
   // if (currentLocation == "media-gallery/pictures"){
   //    $("#menu-item-140").addClass("active");
   // }
});
</script>


<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentLocation = location.pathname;
   // alert(currentLocation);
   if (currentLocation == "/media-gallery/pictures"){
      $("#menu-item-140").addClass("active");
   }
});
</script>
```

:)

EDIT:

To clarify, this code is fully tested, and works, assuming your file is located at http://example.com/test/blank.php.  Please note the leading slash.

```
<style>
    .active{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div id="menu-item-140">Make me red</div>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentLocation = location.pathname;
   alert(currentLocation);
   if (currentLocation == "/test/blank.php"){
      $("#menu-item-140").addClass("active");
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. I alert my url and used that url to active but doesn't work...

Comment: PS: you might need the .php extension, too - please have a look

Comment: I am using wordpress sir

Comment: No worries, it should still work.  Can you share the exact URL you're talking about?  Now that I look closer, I want to confirm that "#menu-item-140" is the "target" "parent nav" you want to affect?

Comment: #menu-item-140 is a dynamic nav item under top main navigation. Under this, I have 3 pages in a dropdown menu.

Comment: OK, I test this on my local machine, and I promise, it works fine.  I set up a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgrigga/wqhRB/  So the code we're talking about works... are you sure you have jquery included? if the url is identical to the results of that alert, and the id is correct, then you have a problem beyond info provided in the question.  please post more info if you have any more clues

Comment: Awesome @WebWebby, glad to hear it... please accept this answer so other will know it's complete

Comment: Ryan how can we make links dynamic?

Since when I prompted the urls, it shows some like my-site/media-gallery/pictures when I want to make the my-site part as dynamic by php, because when I upload to server, i have to change URLs everytime. and may be I can forget this anytime to change.

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but in your original question you said "the page link highlights".  You can do something like $('li.active').parents('ul.parentlink').addClass('active') - I've not tested that but hope you see what i'm sayin'